# Why is PHP removing leading leading zero from request parameter?

Tags: php, string, casting, integer

Im a noob to php and I don't understand why the leading character in my string, which is zero is being removed after I pass it through a url.  Like so: http://sample.com/Sample/employee_select.php?emp=03

When I use $_GET to get the value it returns 3 instead of 03.  How do i keep the leading zero?

this is NOT a duplicate of How to keep leading zeros in PHP integer.

MY CODE

```
 <?php 
 $emp = $_GET['emp']; 
 $tdat = $_GET['tdt'];

 echo $emp; //returns "3" instead of "03"


?>
```

Comment: Yep, this is a dynamic typing issue.

Comment: because php thinks its an int, you want the string "03"

Comment: @Dagon how do i let php know that it is a string/

Comment: @DollaBill you can check the accepted answer in the duplicated question... :)

Comment: The marked duplicate question doesn't seem to answer this question at all. If it does, how ? If I understand correctly, the issue here is different.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer Thank you Lorenz.  The accepted answer is a irrelevant to my situation.

Comment: @DollaBill try casting to a string `echo (string)$emp;`

Comment: @meda Thanks for responding.  I just tried your suggestion and got the same result.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not able to reproduce your problem:

```
echo $_GET['test'];
// outputs 03

echo '<br />';

$temp = $_GET['test'];
echo $temp;
// outputs 03
```

I think your issue is elsewhere. Possibly your PHP version / configuration, MOD Rewrite, or something else in your code that wasn't provided in your example.

Comment: I have the same problem as it is stated in the question.

Comment: @saeedkhalafinejad what version of PHP?

Comment: Version 5, although I solved it by wrapping the number between quotes. That is to write x='001' instead of x=001.